# Unexpected error when changing to landscape mode android

Tags: android, android-service

I am experiencing some unexpected service leaked error when I change activity to landscape mode. The app is running fine, the error only shows up in logcat.

logcat error is :

> E/ActivityThread(16640): Activity com.amazon.hsyal.ui.VoltageSODLoggerActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.amazon.hsyal.ui.VoltageSODLoggerActivity$1@41461908 that was originally bound here
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.amazon.hsyal.ui.VoltageSODLoggerActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.amazon.hsyal.ui.VoltageSODLoggerActivity$1@41461908 that was originally bound here
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:999)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:893)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1139)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:386)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at com.amazon.hsyal.ui.VoltageSODLoggerActivity$2.onClick(VoltageSODLoggerActivity.java:96)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14132)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4492)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>
> E/ActivityThread(16640):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

corresponding onCreate code is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    PowerManager mgr= (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wk = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
    wk.acquire();
    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoggerService.class);
    Button start_stop_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_stop_button);
    start_stop_button.setOnClickListener(startStopButtonListener);

    if(getServiceInfo(this)){
        start_stop_button.setText("Stop Service");

    }else
    {   start_stop_button.setText("Start Service");

    }

}
```

I think there must be some problem in where I am creating instace of service connection. Presently I am doing that in onCreate, do I need to do this some where else also ?

Answer (score 1):

in your code, I can't see an instance of your service connection, only an `Intent` (which is not a connection to your service, as you might know)...

you probably want to bind your service in the `onStart()` and unbind your service in the `onStop()` methods of your activity. also, I would suggest that you'd move your `WakeLock` in your `Service` class, if you don't need your `Activity` to show up all the way...

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html for more details about the `Service` class and how to bind/unbind from a `Service` (instead of using `startService()` and `stopService()`)

Answer (score 1):

When the orientation changes, the activity is recreated, i.e. onDestroy() is invoked and onCreate is invoked again.

You may have forgotten to release your wake lock in the onDestroy() method. Make your wake lock a member variable and invoke

```
wk.release();
```

in your onDestroy() method.